# 'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods

I have a up and running swift 3 application built on XCode 8.1. I was going through feature addition when I added a new pod `Siren` to my `cocoapods` file. I integrated `Siren` quite well to my project and it was up and running. 
And then I added `OneSignal` framework to the app. It was going well until I added a new target as explained on the official link of [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup). This is the `cocoapod` file used in my workspace.

```
 pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.5.2', '< 3.0'

  #network and background utilities
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'

  #visuals

  pod 'HxColor', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'MaterialComponents'
  pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift3'

  #utlities
  pod 'Siren'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'SwifterSwift'

  target 'Toyanath Panchanga - Nepali CalendarTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Toyanath Panchanga - Nepali CalendarUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
  end
```

Whenever I clean or rebuild the project, I get error as **'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead**.
I actually also want to add OneSignal to my new target `NotificationService`.

What should I be doing now? I don't have control to a cocoapod library written by someone else.